# Image doesn't load in react js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have developing an app using spring boot and react js as frontend and backend respectively.

I have a database that consists of "title, image, content" and when I fetch without the frontend, everything works perfectly - I see all the details including the picture that is saved as path.

But the image doesn't display in react...

This is my image tag in react js

```
<img src ={'data:image/jpg;base64,${article.file}'}/>
```

I was expecting everything to display but it's only the title and content that are displaying.

Comment: Either update your question with debugging details or provide a *runnable* [mcve]. Since we don't know the value of `article.file` we have no way of knowing why the image does not render.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided, you are trying to create an  element with a src attribute containing a template literal. However, you have a syntax issue in your template literal. You should use backticks (`) to create a template literal string and ${} to interpolate the value of article.file correctly.

Below is the corrected version.

`` <img src={`data:image/jpg;base64,${article.file}`} alt="Article Image" /> ``

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be with how you are using template literals in your 'img' tag.

The string interpolation syntax with ${...} requires backticks instead of single or double quotes.

Try changing your code to use backticks:

```
<img src={`data:image/jpg;base64,${article.file}`} />
```